# register:1 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'images/1673093609243ali' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

try {
  const userCrdential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    auth,
    email,
    password
  );
  const user = userCrdential.user;
  const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${Date.now() + username}`);
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
  uploadTask.on(
    (error) => {
      toast.error(error.massage);
    },
    () => {
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
        await updateProfile(user, {
          displayName: username,
          photoURL: downloadURL,
        });

        // store data in firebase
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
          uid: user.uid,
          displayName: username,
          email,
          photoURL: downloadURL,
        });
      });
    }
  );
  console.log(user);
} catch (Error) {
  toast. Error("something went wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`UploadTask.on` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.uploadtask.md#uploadtaskon) takes 4 parameters including 3 callbacks, but you're passing no value for the event type to listen for and only passing two callbacks. My guess is that your call to `getDownloadURL` runs before the upload has completed, and thus can't find the file yet.

I recommend using the fact that the task returned by `uploadBytesResumable` is also a `Promise` to make this code much more familiar:

```
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
uploadTask.then(() => {
    getDownloadURL(storageRef).then((downloadURL) => {
      ...
    });
  })
}).catch((error) => {
  toast.error(error.massage);
})
```